# DCOM Configuration for Microsoft Office 2007 - unable to open the document template (.dotm)

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop, dcom, word-automation

I am using Microsoft Word Automation for generating documents. The application is working on one system, but not on other.

The problem with another system is that I once corrupted its registry by mistake. But, I have uninstalled and re-installed Microsoft Office several times. It seems that Office installation and deinstallation doesn't reset its dcom configuation settings, which is why my application is unable to attach the .dotm file.

The server where it is working, the settings are as follows:

[image: working system dcom settings]

but, the system where it is not working, the "Local Path" is showing up as blank value. I believe this is the only problem for my issue.

Any clues how can I restore these settings back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182248), those configurations such as local path are extracted from the registry and are not modifiable:

**(...)** The General tab provides general information about the application. This tab displays the Application name, type (local server or remote server), and location (local path or remote computer). These settings are not modifiable through the DCOM Config interface.

The General Tab retrieves all of its information from subkeys of the following registry key:
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{...CLSID...}
where {...CLSID...} is the unique CLSID for the Object Server currently being viewed. **(...)**

So! Run > regedit > Go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID, then go to Edit menu and click Find, filter by key and put your ApplicationID there. You should find it this way.

Now after finding the registry entry for your DCOM, expand it, you should see a LocalServer32, the property (Default) holds your Local Path value, try change it the same path as in your new Oracle Virtual Box.

If this works, test if the value hold after restarting and logging in with you Domain User account if it does, great, if not, run a batch to run a .reg file to perform this modification, on every login.